# "if at all" vs "if any" vs "if ever"

Tags: phrase-choice, idiomatic-language

What is the deference in the usage of "if at all", "if any" and "if ever". Specifically, which one is the right choice in the following sentence?

> It is not clear what bearing, ------, A has on B.

Answer (score 2):

The right answer is "if any."

**If at all** is an *adverbial* phrase of *degree*.

**If ever** is an *adverbial* phrase of *time*.

**If any** is an *adjectival* phrase.

In your example, "if any" modifies "bearing." Note that you can also say "if any at all" if you want to emphasize that it's *probably none*. "If any" is more neutral to the possibility that A may have some bearing on B.

An example where "if at all" would be correct ("if at all" modifies "will affect"):

> The new rules won't affect them very much, if at all.

An example where "if ever" would be correct ("if ever" modifies "will return"):

> I doubt I'll return very often, if ever.